# characteristic polynomial of a matrix which is "nearly" diagonal

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Is there an easy way to compute the characteristic polynomial of a matrix which is "nearly" diagonal? Example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &0 & 0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

it is "nearly" diagonal. If the both entries in the left lower corner would be 0, I just could compute the eigenvalues to be $0$ by
$$
det(A-\lambda I)=(-\lambda)^{10} =0
$$

Comment: We can reduce such matrix block-wise and then compute eigenvalues and characterstic polynomial I guess not sure.

Comment: You mean, by minors?

Comment: Yes, Something like that only because for such kind of matrix that is nearly diagonal it is easier to calculate using block matrices so might be helpful.

Comment: As an aside, the determinant of $A$ is obviously zero, seen from the fact that the final two columns are identical.  As for the determinant of $(A-\lambda I)$, I personally haven't seen any useful tricks for this situation.

Comment: $\lambda^{10} - \lambda^3-\lambda^2$, Laplace way.